# Stripe + Plaid not available for .Net right now

Tags: node.js, .net, asp.net-core, stripe-payments, plaid

I have web application in  .Net Core 3.1 and using Razor Pages.
I want to integrate ACH payment but stripe + Plaid ACH not available for .Net. (https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid).

It is available for nodejs, Is there any way that I can use one nodejs package in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plaid doesn't offer a .NET library, but you can still [manually collect and verify bank accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#manually-collecting-and-verifying-bank-accounts) with .NET.